# How to avoid warning Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<Facility>

Tags: java

The following code segment results in a warning "Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList" for the second last line in Eclipse.  Just wondering what I can do to improve it.  the code is used to read objects from an xml file.

```
private List<Facility> getFacilityCodes() {
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("./resources/facility.xml");
    String xml = convertStreamToString(in);
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.alias("Facility", Facility.class);
    xstream.alias("Facilities", List.class);
    ArrayList<Facility> facilities = (ArrayList<Facility>) xstream.fromXML(xml);
    return facilities;
}
```

Comment: How was the serialized XML created? What object type does it contain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the cast will succeed as long as the returned object is an `ArrayList`, but it can't guarantee that every element is a `Facility` because of erasure. You can do that yourself, if you wish.

```
ArrayList<Facility> facilities =
    ((ArrayList<?>) xstream.fromXML(xml)).stream()
                                         .filter(Facility.class::isInstance)
                                         .map(Facility.class::cast)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Thank you, however I am getting an "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to ArrayList<Facility>"

Comment: Thank you - perfect.  That warning has been in the code for years....  much appreciated

Comment: @skyman It might be appropriate to check that each element is a `Facility` and throw an exception otherwise, rather than filtering them out.

Comment: yes, true and in the early stages of the project that was an issue - ie if the xml was corrupt